# Can't understand what professor is saying. LL(1) parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I'm reading it again and again but can't understand.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/09c45nhted

A few things i dont understand:

Epsilon meaning, aside from "empty string".

$ meaning

How R3 is possible? It has term which would go to factor which would go to something that is not exist in input stream.

3rd bullet point on second page

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask]. As of now, this question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: ε exactly means "nothing at all". $ means end-of-input (by convention). R3 says that a term-tail is an add-op followed by a term followed by a term-tail; an add-op is either a `+` or a `-` (rules 11 and 12), so it will match the next token in the input, which is a `+`. And this is not an appropriate SO question.

Comment: @EngineerDollery should i delete it?

Comment: You could rewrite it containing the information hidden behind that link, or you can delete it. If you wait a few hours this will probably be deleted for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Epsilon meaning, aside from "empty string"?

This ϵ symbol in the simplest way means nothing.

> $ meaning ?

$ can mean either the starting of input OR the end of input. But,here it means the `end of input` as starting of input can't start with $ because of such CFG having start state `stmt`.

> How R3 is possible? It has term which would go to factor which would
>   go to something that is not exist in input stream.

Beginners have problem dealing with this kind of thing. It's normal and should be. This kind of production is kind of recursive production.But,it will get resolved easily on parsing the input. You can notice the next production R4 : term_tail---> ϵ. Whenever substitution of term_tail won't require any input, then this production can be used to deal with that stage. So, no infinite recursion as to what you might have been thinking...

> 3rd bullet point on second page?

**It is the input character that can follow term_tail in the grammar.** This statement is the answer to the question mentioned in second bullet point *"So what input character can be consumed if we apply R4?"* Actually, the input string that is going to be derived for the term_tail can be done in 2 ways :-

```
EITHER term_tail ---> add_op term term_tail   OR   term_tail ---> ϵ
```

Through the help of those bulleted points, ***the author is trying to highlight the practical significance of FOLLOW() function in top-down parsing***. The author's intent is to evaluate the conditions on which R4 can be applied on top-down parsing as mentioned on the top of 2nd page "the possible input characters for which R4 can be applied?".

The `FOLLOW() of term_tail` comes out to be '$',')'. You will be able to calculate this when you'll study FOLLOW() function's rules.

**NOTE (VERY-VERY IMPORTANT) :-**

1. FOLLOW() shows us the terminals that can come after a derived non-terminal. Note, this does not mean the last terminal derived from a non-terminal. It's the set of terminals that can come after it. We define FOLLOW() for all the non-terminals in the grammar.
2. How do we figure out FOLLOW()? Instead of looking at the first terminal for each phrase on the right side of the arrow, we find every place our non-terminal is located on the right side of any of the arrows. Then we look for some terminals.